# os.popen: How to integrate output and data from file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, stdout, popen

I have a basic script that reads a file which has package names to build a command string and I store in a variable.
I then call a `os.popen` to run the command and store the output to a variable for further processing.

I loop over the variable looking for an 'Error:' string and if there is a match it prints it. All works good but it just prints the error which is what I want but I also want to know which package caused the error even if I include the package variable I only get the error.

Here are the contents of the file:

```
kernel-3.10.0-1160.el7
openshift-clients-4.3.7-202003130552.git.0.6027a27.el7
NetworkManager-config-server-1.18.8-1.el7
python2-psutil-5.6.6-1.el7ar
systemd-219-67.el7_7.1.x86_64
```

Here is the script:

```
import os
import sys
f=open("data1", "r")
for pkg in f:
  #print(pkg)
  command='yum --showduplicates list + ' +pkg
  with os.popen(command) as results_in:
    for item in results_in:
        if 'Error:' in item:
            print(item + "package name:" + pkg)
```

Here is the results of the script:

```
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

I was hoping to get the error + package name.

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to make the proper adjustments?

Comment: It looks to me like it should print the package name right after the error message, just as you intended.

Comment: Try changing it to `+ pkg.strip()` to remove CRLF

Comment: I tired that but it still just produces the same message which is just the error but not the error and the package.  I did create the same script but I used another command ping and I'm able to extract a message from the ping output and the IP from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yum` is writing the error message to `stderr`, not `stdout`. What you're seeing is the error message being printed by `yum`, not from your script.

You need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` so you can capture it and check it.

It's also a good idea to remove the trailing newline from the line being read from the file, so do `pkg = pkg.strip()`

```
command=f'yum --showduplicates list ' + pkg + ' 2>&1'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried that with the same syntax as you suggested and I get this:    line 7
    command=f'yum --showduplicates list {pkg} 2>&1'.    I updated the command to look like this command='yum --showduplicates list '+ pkg + ' 2>&1' and I get the expected error but not the package name.

Comment: You need Python 3.6 to use f-strings.

Comment: I tried it on 3.6 and same results. Here is the var I added  command=f'yum --showduplicates list ' + pkg + ' 2>&1'

Comment: That just fixes the f-string syntax error, it has nothing to do with the rest of the problem.

Comment: And if you're using an f-string, why are you still using concatenation?

Comment: Did you add `pkg = pkg.strip()` like I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the script another way to get the data I'm looking for. Thank you for your help! You sparked the idea of stderr so I chased that method to capture it and respond based on that.

```
import subprocess
import shlex
f=open("data1", "r")
for pkg in f:
  command='yum list available ' + pkg
  proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 output = proc.stdout.readline()
 stdout, stderr= proc.communicate()
 if 'Error' in str(stderr, 'utf-8').strip():
    print("Error not available: "+pkg)
 else:
    print("Package available: "+pkg)
```